# Referencing interfaces from other contracts

Tags: solidity, erc-20

I am trying to deploy a contract which has an external function with no implementation body. Remix and truffle have problems with this. I know that abstract interfaces can't be deployed, but how were contracts like this deployed? The deposit function is empty :https://etherscan.io/address/0xc7029Ed9EBa97A096e72607f4340c34049C7AF48#code

My contract has a function similar to

```
    function deposit()
    external
    payable { }
```

I planned to reference my deployed contract using something like:

```
DeployedInterface constant private DeployedCOntract = DeployedInterface(deployedInterfaceAddress);
```

Comment: You can deploy a function with an empty body just fine. What you can't do is deploy a function with no body. (E.g. `foo() { }` is fine, but `foo();` is not.)